# How to reference or join a table that has a varchar primary key with a table that has an INT primary Key (SQL server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, compiler-errors

This is the database I am using.

[image: Database]

What I want to do is reference or join the department table into the project table.
I should be able to use the following query successfully. I need this queries specific result

```
SELECT P.ProjectID, P.ProjectName, P.Department, D.BudgetCode
FROM DEPARTMENT D, PROJECT P
```

This query executes successfully. However, I get duplicate values in my result and it is not formatted properly. This is the result I get

```
ProjectID   ProjectName                     Department      BudgetCode
1000        2010 Q3 Product Plan            Marketing       BC-300-10                     
1000        2010 Q3 Product Plan            Marketing       BC-100-10                     
1000        2010 Q3 Product Plan            Marketing       BC-400-10                     
1000        2010 Q3 Product Plan            Marketing       BC-500-10                     
1000        2010 Q3 Product Plan            Marketing       BC-800-10                     
1000        2010 Q3 Product Plan            Marketing       BC-200-10                     
1000        2010 Q3 Product Plan            Marketing       BC-700-10                     
1000        2010 Q3 Product Plan            Marketing       BC-600-10                     
1100        2010 Q3 Portfolio Analysis      Finance         BC-300-10                     
1100        2010 Q3 Portfolio Analysis      Finance         BC-100-10                     
1100        2010 Q3 Portfolio Analysis      Finance         BC-400-10                     
1100        2010 Q3 Portfolio Analysis      Finance         BC-500-10                     
1100        2010 Q3 Portfolio Analysis      Finance         BC-800-10                     
1100        2010 Q3 Portfolio Analysis      Finance         BC-200-10                     
1100        2010 Q3 Portfolio Analysis      Finance         BC-700-10                     
1100        2010 Q3 Portfolio Analysis      Finance         BC-600-10                     
1200        2010 Q3 Tax Preparation         Accounting      BC-300-10                     
1200        2010 Q3 Tax Preparation         Accounting      BC-100-10                     
1200        2010 Q3 Tax Preparation         Accounting      BC-400-10                     
1200        2010 Q3 Tax Preparation         Accounting      BC-500-10                     
1200        2010 Q3 Tax Preparation         Accounting      BC-800-10                     
1200        2010 Q3 Tax Preparation         Accounting      BC-200-10                     
1200        2010 Q3 Tax Preparation         Accounting      BC-700-10                     
1200        2010 Q3 Tax Preparation         Accounting      BC-600-10                     
1300        2010 Q4 Product Plan            Marketing       BC-300-10                     
1300        2010 Q4 Product Plan            Marketing       BC-100-10                     
1300        2010 Q4 Product Plan            Marketing       BC-400-10                     
1300        2010 Q4 Product Plan            Marketing       BC-500-10                     
1300        2010 Q4 Product Plan            Marketing       BC-800-10                     
1300        2010 Q4 Product Plan            Marketing       BC-200-10                     
1300        2010 Q4 Product Plan            Marketing       BC-700-10                     
1300        2010 Q4 Product Plan            Marketing       BC-600-10                     
1400        2010 Q4 Portfolio Analysis      Finance         BC-300-10                     
1400        2010 Q4 Portfolio Analysis      Finance         BC-100-10                     
1400        2010 Q4 Portfolio Analysis      Finance         BC-400-10                     
1400        2010 Q4 Portfolio Analysis      Finance         BC-500-10                     
1400        2010 Q4 Portfolio Analysis      Finance         BC-800-10                     
1400        2010 Q4 Portfolio Analysis      Finance         BC-200-10                     
1400        2010 Q4 Portfolio Analysis      Finance         BC-700-10                     
1400        2010 Q4 Portfolio Analysis      Finance         BC-600-10
```

I need to get this result instead

[image]

I tried using a JOIN:

```
SELECT P.ProjectID, P.ProjectName, P.Department, D.BudgetCode
FROM DEPARTMENT D
RIGHT JOIN PROJECT P ON P.ProjectID = D.DepartmentName
```

But I get a conversion error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Accounting' to data type int.

Which i assume is because its not possible to convert a varchar to an int. Unless a cast may work...

```
SELECT P.ProjectID, P.ProjectName, P.Department, D.BudgetCode
FROM DEPARTMENT D
RIGHT JOIN PROJECT P ON cast(P.ProjectID AS varchar) = D.DepartmentName
```

Using the cast, I got this result

```
ProjectID   ProjectName                     Department      BudgetCode
1000        2010 Q3 Product Plan            Marketing       NULL
1100        2010 Q3 Portfolio Analysis      Finance         NULL
1200        2010 Q3 Tax Preparation         Accounting      NULL
1300        2010 Q4 Product Plan            Marketing       NULL
1400        2010 Q4 Portfolio Analysis      Finance         NULL
```

This is almost what i was looking for, but it shows NULL values for my BudgetCodes, witch is not correct. They are not null values.

So at this point, I'm out of ideas.
(As a side note, I understand that in my database i have a varchar as a primary key, and i was trying to JOIN that primary key with a Primary key that was an int. If they were of the same type, Im sure my join would have worked)

Comment: You are getting nulls because `JOIN` couldn't find any matching rows. Are you sure that you are joining on the right columns? From what I can see there's `Department.DepartmentName` column - wouldn't it match `Project.Department`? It seems highly unlikely that `Department.DepartmentName` equals `Project.ProjectID`. Could you provide an example of rows in `Department` table?

Comment: Thanks man you were right. I tried using P.Department = D.DepartmentName and it worked, if you post that as an answer ill accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Project.Department is a forigen key to Department.DepartmentName then you can join by that.

```
JOIN Project P ON P.Department = D.DepartmentName
```

if not, you need to see which column is shared between the two tables Project and Department, and link both tables by that column. shared column needs to have the same datatype on both tables.

Another tip, you're querying Department and JOIN Projects, and in the same time, you only use BudgetCode from Department, and the rest are from Project. In this case, you need to query Project and JOIN Department.

```
SELECT 
    P.ProjectID, 
    P.ProjectName, 
    P.Department, 
    D.BudgetCode
FROM PROJECT P
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT D ON D.DepartmentName = P.Department
```

Comment: For some reason I thought I could only join with primary keys, but now I know, thanks

Comment: @programming__God Yes you should always join by Primary Key, which will assure the uniqueness of the linked data. However, if for some reason can't join directly to a primary key, but you have another column that you know for sure has a unique values, then you could use that. Linking tables with columns that have duplicated entities will give you inaccurate results. That's why you should always aim for primary key.

Comment: @iSR5 Your statement "you should always join by Primary Key" is not entirely true. Primary keys of two relations do not have to mean the same thing. Joining on any other column is perfectly fine and it doesn't have to be unique. It depends on the domain you're modelling. You may need to create an index for that column if that helps with performance. One thing you should do is create a Foreign Key to ensure the consistency of your data. In the example above `Project.Department` column is clearly a foreign key to `Department` table.

Comment: @IgorNikolaev I think I spelled it wrong, what I meant by a primary key is that the main link (in general) should be treated with primary key and its foreign key, this is the preferred way. But its true, it's not necessary to be linked that way, as it depends on the domain as you mention.  You could join in any way you see fits according to your schema structure.